# Exporting a material with multiple diffuse textures in COLLADA format

Tags: export, collada

I need a Blender export format that handles materials with multiple diffuse textures in it. Specifically, I want to export a mesh with a single material and two diffuse textures and a single stencil map. The blender COLLADA exporter appears to ignore two out of the three textures in my material. All three are referenced in the export file as:

```
<library_images>
   <image id="Grass_1_png" name="Grass_1_png">
     <init_from>Grass_1.png</init_from>
   </image>
   <image id="stencilmap" name="stencilmap">
     <init_from>stencilmap.png</init_from>
   </image>
   <image id="BlueMarbleSlabs_png" name="BlueMarbleSlabs_png">
     <init_from>BlueMarbleSlabs.png</init_from>
   </image>
</library_images>
```

However the library effect diffuse component only references the last texture in the material texture stack:

```
<diffuse>
    <texture texture="BlueMarbleSlabs_png-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
</diffuse>
```

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of the COLLADA exporter? If this is the case then I'll need to modify the Assimp COLLADA loader for my purposes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try blender baking, so you retrieve one uv map with one texture for entire object. [https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html](http://%20https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html)

Comment: Could you upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/